# loop for Scraping data

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, user-defined-functions

i want to scrape data from website and make loop from this code

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import numpy as np

all_data_df = pd.DataFrame()
script = """
function waitCss(selector, n=1, require=false, timeout=5000) {
  console.log(selector, n, require, timeout);
  var start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - start < timeout){
    if (document.querySelectorAll(selector).length >= n){
      return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    }
  }
  if (require){
      throw new Error(`selector "${selector}" timed out in ${Date.now() - start} ms`);
  } else {
      return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }
}
var results = waitCss("div.w6VYqd", n=100, require=false);
var placesData = [];
results.forEach(function(result){
  var nameElement = result.querySelector("div.NrDZNb");
  var ratingElement = result.querySelector("span.MW4etd");
  var reviewCountElement = result.querySelector("span.UY7F9");
  var typeElement = result.querySelector("div.W4Efsd");
  var name = nameElement ? nameElement.innerText : "";
  var rating = ratingElement ? ratingElement.innerText : "";
  var reviewCount = reviewCountElement ? reviewCountElement.innerText : "";
  var type = typeElement ? typeElement.innerText : "";
  placesData.push({
    name: name,
    rating: rating,
    reviewCount: reviewCount,
    type: type
  });
});
return placesData;
"""
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

latitude1 = lat
longitude1 = lon

df1 = []
df2 = []
df3 = []
df4 = []

#for find1
find1 = ["type1", "type2"]
district = [ 'district1','district2']
for district in district:
    for place_type in find:
        query = f"{place_type}+in+{district}/@{latitude1},{longitude1}"
        url = f"AAA/{query.replace(' ', '+')}"
        driver.get(url)
        ele = None
        while ele is None:  # retry_next:
            try:
                next_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="TFQHme "]')
                next_btn.click()
                time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the sleep time as needed
                no_scroll = 20  # Increase or decrease this value to scroll more or less
                for page_down in range(0, no_scroll):
                    ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                              '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]')
                    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 5000);', ele)
                    time.sleep(2)
                for i in range(1, 1000, 2):
                    address_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                          "//*[@id='QA0Szd']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[" + str(
                                                              i) + "]/div")
                    url_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                      "//*[@id='QA0Szd']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[" + str(
                                                          i) + "]/div/a")
                    address = address_element.text
                    url = url_element.get_attribute("href")
                    url = str(url)
                    lat_log = url.split('!')
                    lat = lat_log[5].split('3d')
                    lat1 = lat[1]
                    log = lat_log[6].split('4d')
                    log1 = log[1]
                    address = address.split('\n')
                    print(url)
                    df1.append(url)
                    print(address)
                    df2.append(address)
                    print(lat1)
                    print(log1)
                    df3.append(lat1)
                    df4.append(log1)
            except:
                print("Cannot find next button")
                break
    
            if len(df1) == 0:
                continue
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df2 = df2.iloc[:, :3]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(df4)
df5 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df5 = pd.concat([df5, df3], axis=1)
df5 = pd.concat([df5, df4], axis=1)
df5 = pd.DataFrame(df5)

columns = ['URL', 'Name', 'Review', 'Type_Address', 'lat', 'log']
result_df = df5
result_df.columns = columns
result_df[['Review_rating', 'Review_Amt']] = result_df['Review'].str.split('(', n=1, expand=True)
result_df[['Review_rating', 'Review_Amt1']] = result_df['Review'].str.split('(', n=1, expand=True)
result_df[['Review_Amt', ' ']] = result_df['Review_Amt1'].str.split(')', n=1, expand=True)
result_df[['Type', 'Address']] = result_df['Type_Address'].str.split(' · ', n=1, expand=True)

result_df['LAT_LOG'] = result_df['lat'] + "," + result_df['log']

result_df['lat'] = result_df['lat'].astype('float64')
result_df['log'] = result_df['log'].astype('float64')

result_df['Shop_type'] = place_type

result_df = result_df[['URL', 'Name', 'Review_rating', 'Review_Amt', 'Shop_type', 'Type', 'lat', 'log', 'Address','LAT_LOG']]

result_df = result_df.drop_duplicates(subset='URL', keep='first')
result_df1 = result_df

result_df1.to_excel('my_scrape.xlsx')

driver.quit()


all_data_df = pd.DataFrame()
script = """
function waitCss(selector, n=1, require=false, timeout=5000) {
  console.log(selector, n, require, timeout);
  var start = Date.now();
  while (Date.now() - start < timeout){
    if (document.querySelectorAll(selector).length >= n){
      return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    }
  }
  if (require){
      throw new Error(`selector "${selector}" timed out in ${Date.now() - start} ms`);
  } else {
      return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  }
}
var results = waitCss("div.w6VYqd", n=100, require=false);
var placesData = [];
results.forEach(function(result){
  var nameElement = result.querySelector("div.NrDZNb");
  var ratingElement = result.querySelector("span.MW4etd");
  var reviewCountElement = result.querySelector("span.UY7F9");
  var typeElement = result.querySelector("div.W4Efsd");
  var name = nameElement ? nameElement.innerText : "";
  var rating = ratingElement ? ratingElement.innerText : "";
  var reviewCount = reviewCountElement ? reviewCountElement.innerText : "";
  var type = typeElement ? typeElement.innerText : "";
  placesData.push({
    name: name,
    rating: rating,
    reviewCount: reviewCount,
    type: type
  });
});
return placesData;
"""
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

latitude1 = lat
longitude1 = lon

df1 = []
df2 = []
df3 = []
df4 = []

#for find2
find2 = ["type3", "type4"]
district = [ 'district1','district2']
for district in district:
    for place_type in find:
        query = f"{place_type}+in+{district}/@{latitude1},{longitude1}"
        url = f"https://www.google.com/maps/search/{query.replace(' ', '+')}/?hl=en"
        driver.get(url)
        ele = None
        while ele is None:  # retry_next:
            try:
                next_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="TFQHme "]')
                next_btn.click()
                time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the sleep time as needed
                no_scroll = 20  # Increase or decrease this value to scroll more or less
                for page_down in range(0, no_scroll):
                    ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                              '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]')
                    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 5000);', ele)
                    time.sleep(2)
                for i in range(1, 1000, 2):
                    address_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                          "//*[@id='QA0Szd']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[" + str(
                                                              i) + "]/div")
                    url_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                      "//*[@id='QA0Szd']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[" + str(
                                                          i) + "]/div/a")
                    address = address_element.text
                    url = url_element.get_attribute("href")
                    url = str(url)
                    lat_log = url.split('!')
                    lat = lat_log[5].split('3d')
                    lat1 = lat[1]
                    log = lat_log[6].split('4d')
                    log1 = log[1]
                    address = address.split('\n')
                    print(url)
                    df1.append(url)
                    print(address)
                    df2.append(address)
                    print(lat1)
                    print(log1)
                    df3.append(lat1)
                    df4.append(log1)
            except:
                print("Cannot find next button")
                break
    
            if len(df1) == 0:
                continue
    
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
df2 = df2.iloc[:, :3]
df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
df4 = pd.DataFrame(df4)
df5 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
df5 = pd.concat([df5, df3], axis=1)
df5 = pd.concat([df5, df4], axis=1)
df5 = pd.DataFrame(df5)

columns = ['URL', 'Name', 'Review', 'Type_Address', 'lat', 'log']
result_df = df5
result_df.columns = columns
result_df[['Review_rating', 'Review_Amt']] = result_df['Review'].str.split('(', n=1, expand=True)
result_df[['Review_rating', 'Review_Amt1']] = result_df['Review'].str.split('(', n=1, expand=True)
result_df[['Review_Amt', ' ']] = result_df['Review_Amt1'].str.split(')', n=1, expand=True)
result_df[['Type', 'Address']] = result_df['Type_Address'].str.split(' · ', n=1, expand=True)

result_df['LAT_LOG'] = result_df['lat'] + "," + result_df['log']

result_df['lat'] = result_df['lat'].astype('float64')
result_df['log'] = result_df['log'].astype('float64')

result_df['Shop_type'] = place_type

result_df = result_df[['URL', 'Name', 'Review_rating', 'Review_Amt', 'Shop_type', 'Type', 'lat', 'log', 'Address','LAT_LOG']]

result_df = result_df.drop_duplicates(subset='URL', keep='first')
result_df1 = result_df

result_df1.to_excel('my_scrape.xlsx')

driver.quit()
```

and this is code loop i made

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import numpy as np


def scrape_function(district, place_type):
    all_data_df = pd.DataFrame()
    script = """
    function waitCss(selector, n=1, require=false, timeout=5000) {
      console.log(selector, n, require, timeout);
      var start = Date.now();
      while (Date.now() - start < timeout){
        if (document.querySelectorAll(selector).length >= n){
          return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
        }
      }
      if (require){
          throw new Error(`selector "${selector}" timed out in ${Date.now() - start} ms`);
      } else {
          return document.querySelectorAll(selector);
      }
    }
    var results = waitCss("div.w6VYqd", n=100, require=false);
    var placesData = [];
    results.forEach(function(result){
      var nameElement = result.querySelector("div.NrDZNb");
      var ratingElement = result.querySelector("span.MW4etd");
      var reviewCountElement = result.querySelector("span.UY7F9");
      var typeElement = result.querySelector("div.W4Efsd");
      var name = nameElement ? nameElement.innerText : "";
      var rating = ratingElement ? ratingElement.innerText : "";
      var reviewCount = reviewCountElement ? reviewCountElement.innerText : "";
      var type = typeElement ? typeElement.innerText : "";
      placesData.push({
        name: name,
        rating: rating,
        reviewCount: reviewCount,
        type: type
      });
    });
    return placesData;
    """
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    for district in districts:
        for place_type in find:
            query = f"{place_type}+{district}/@{latitude1},{longitude1}"
            url = f"AAA{query.replace(' ', '+')}"
            driver.get(url)
            ele = None
            while ele is None:  # retry_next:
                try:
                    next_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@class="TFQHme "]')
                    next_btn.click()
                    time.sleep(5)  # Adjust the sleep time as needed
                    no_scroll = 20  # Increase or decrease this value to scroll more or less
                    for page_down in range(0, no_scroll):
                        ele = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                  '//*[@id="QA0Szd"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]')
                        driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollBy(0, 5000);', ele)
                        time.sleep(2)
                    for i in range(3, 1000, 2):
                        address_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                              "//*[@id='QA0Szd']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[" + str(
                                                                  i) + "]/div")
                        url_element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH,
                                                          "//*[@id='QA0Szd']/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[" + str(
                                                              i) + "]/div/a")
                        address = address_element.text
                        url = url_element.get_attribute("href")
                        url = str(url)
                        lat_log = url.split('!')
                        lat = lat_log[5].split('3d')
                        lat1 = lat[1]
                        log = lat_log[6].split('4d')
                        log1 = log[1]
                        address = address.split('\n')
                        print(url)
                        df1.append(url)
                        print(address)
                        df2.append(address)
                        print(lat1)
                        print(log1)
                        df3.append(lat1)
                        df4.append(log1)
                except:
                    print("Cannot find next button")
                    break

                if len(df1) == 0:
                    continue

        df1 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
        df2 = pd.DataFrame(df2)
        df2 = df2.iloc[:, :3]
        df3 = pd.DataFrame(df3)
        df4 = pd.DataFrame(df4)
        df5 = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
        df5 = pd.concat([df5, df3], axis=1)
        df5 = pd.concat([df5, df4], axis=1)
        df5 = pd.DataFrame(df5)

        columns = ['URL', 'Name', 'Review', 'Type_Address', 'lat', 'log']
        result_df = df5
        result_df.columns = columns
        result_df[['Review_rating', 'Review_Amt']] = result_df['Review'].str.split('(', n=1, expand=True)
        result_df[['Review_rating', 'Review_Amt1']] = result_df['Review'].str.split('(', n=1, expand=True)
        result_df[['Review_Amt', ' ']] = result_df['Review_Amt1'].str.split(')', n=1, expand=True)
        result_df[['Type', 'Address']] = result_df['Type_Address'].str.split(' · ', n=1, expand=True)

        result_df['LAT_LOG'] = result_df['lat'] + "," + result_df['log']

        result_df['lat'] = result_df['lat'].astype('float64')
        result_df['log'] = result_df['log'].astype('float64')

        result_df['Shop_type'] = "global house"

        result_df = result_df[
            ['URL', 'Name', 'Review_rating', 'Review_Amt', 'Shop_type', 'Type', 'lat', 'log', 'Address', 'LAT_LOG']]

        result_df = result_df.drop_duplicates(subset='URL', keep='first')
        result_df1 = result_df

        result_df1.to_excel(f'{place_type}_{district}.xlsx')

        driver.quit()


latitude1 = lat
longitude1 = lon

df1 = []
df2 = []
df3 = []
df4 = []

find = {find2:["type3", "type4"],
        find2:["type3", "type4"]}
district = [ 'district1','district2']


for district in districts:
    for place_type in find:
        for specific_type in find:

            scrape_function(district,place_type)
```

I want to iterate over the query and find the elements. When the search ends I want to repeat the next question to create a loop where iterates over place_type and district then save file as find1_district.xlsx and find2_district.xlsx, my code fist can scrape but my loop def code not scrape

From the first code that hasn't looped, I can scrape the data normally. But when I loop it back it says "Cannot find next button" which is wrong than what I did separately. Don't know if you can help me fix it or create a loop for me.